# Animate the appearance of a new Grid column inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a CollectionView with a Grid inside the DataTemplate. With the TapGestureRecognizer event I make a new column appear or not within the Grid itself.

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <yummy:PancakeView CornerRadius="5" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
         <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray" Opacity="0.8" RowSpacing="0.1">
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="36"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="23"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="14"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ClickedDiario_Tapped"/>
         </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
         <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="{Binding ColoreUmore}"/>
         <Image Source="{Binding Umore}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3"/>
         <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding GiornoTrascritto}" FontSize="9" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
         <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Orario}" FontSize="11" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="3"/>

         <CollectionView
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Grid.RowSpan="3"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            IsVisible="{Binding Edit}"
            //other...
```

When I make visible the CollectionView placed inside the DataTemplate, I would like the visualization to happen through a scrolling animation, but inside the DataTemplate I would not know how to animate

**this is my code c#:**

```
 private void ClickedDiario_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       var grid = sender as Grid;
       var selectedItem = grid.BindingContext as HumorDiary;
       selectedItem.Edit = true;
 }
```

Comment: Side question is it necessary to have a CollectionView nested inside a CollectionView DataTemplate there is no way around?

Comment: If I wanted I could insert a FlexLayout, but I don't create a problem for the animation at the moment, right?

Comment: Like [Expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander)?

Comment: yes, but how do I get the object inside the DataTemplate?

Comment: Could you describe more clearly what you are going to do ?